# Display order in woocommerce admin list status and user wise

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

In woocommerce in order list in admin side I want to display orders by status.

I mean to say if order has processing status then and then that order should display in admin order list and other orders should not display in that list. Check image for more details what I need..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uffG.png)

Comment: If you check just above the order list you can find the "view filters". They are already doing what u're trying to do, isn't it?

Comment: Nope..I want to get done this pragmatically..as in my project there will different users and user A can see few orders and user B can see few orders..so by default this list should display only that orders which are processing status..

Comment: Sorry but we expect you to provide your real code attempt in your question. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research, post a [Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and specifically say where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this?

```
/**
 * Limit statuses dropdown for custom user role.
 *
 * @param array $statuses
 * @see wc_get_order_statuses()
 */
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', function( $statuses ) {
    # Custom user role (registered elsewhere).
    $custom_user_role = 'administrator';
    
    # Status(es) of orders to show to custom user role.
    $limit_to_order_statuses = array(
        'wc-processing' => 1,
        'wc-on-hold' => 1,
    );
    
    # Make sure we're editing right query.
    # If not, then nothing to change ("return early").
    if (
        !function_exists( 'get_current_screen' )
        ||  'shop_order' !== get_current_screen()->post_type
        || 'woocommerce' !== get_current_screen()->parent_base
    )
        return $statuses;
    
    # Check if user has the specified custom user role.
    # If they don't, then nothing to change ("return early").
    if ( !in_array( $custom_user_role, wp_get_current_user()->roles ) )
        return $statuses;
    
    return array_intersect_key( $statuses, $limit_to_order_statuses );
} );
```

Credit goes to https://wordpress.org/support/topic/order-status-visibility-by-role/ (Kingfisher64)

Comment: Thanks for reply..yes it worked for me..I made little bit change and get it working..

Comment: can you please see here..if you can help me in that..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63424922/woocommerce-display-order-based-on-meta-key-stored